# Multiple uploads Wistia

Tags: file-upload, upload

I'm implementing Wistia on my site. And I'm adding multiple uploads (to be decided by the user) simultaneously. It's working fine technical way, but progress bars stay still and only one progress in. When this ends the other progress.

It will be some configuration problem? Can I make all the progress bars work together?

Thanks